# Trigger the mono soft debugger at runtime

Tags: mono, soft-debugger

I can already debug easily using the soft debugger as a command line option (`--debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=host:port`) to mono when starting the app, but I want my program to continue if it can't find a debugger listening or better still for it to be told to connect to a specific monodevelop soft debugger later at runtime.

Looking at the [Mono.Debugger.Soft](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=N%3aMono.Debugger.Soft) API I think this could be possible, are there any examples?

Comment: Unluckily for you Debugger.Launch() hasn't been implemented in mono yet :(